# Flashing Bios of ROG STRIX Z370-E Motherboard for compatibility with 9th gen Intel CPU

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

I ordered an Intel i7-9700k processor without realizing it was only compatible with motherboards that support 9th generation processors.  The motherboard I bought is the ROG STRIX Z370-E Gaming board.  I have read that this board has the correct socket to support the 9th gen but in order to make it work the BIOS has to be "flashed" with an update.

I have a USB drive ready but I'm not sure which BIOS version I need. I know it can be found on the Asus.com/support website. I just don't understand if I should be looking for just a new BIOS version for my exact motherboard, or for something else such as the ROG STRIX Z390 which supports 9th gen.  I was hoping someone here has done this and can give me some advice. Thank you all for reading

Answer (score 0):

> I ordered an Intel i7-9700k processor without realizing it was only compatible with motherboards that support 9th generation processors.

The `ROG STRIX Z370-E Gaming` supports all of Intel's 9th generation processors.

> I have a USB drive ready but I'm not sure which BIOS version I need.

i7-9700k is supported by revision 1002.  However, 1412 is the current revision, so you should install that.  You can download the supported firmware for your processor [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z370-E-GAMING/HelpDesk_BIOS/)

> I just don't understand if I should be looking for just a new BIOS version for my exact motherboard, or for something else such as the ROG STRIX Z390 which supports 9th gen.

The purchase of a new motherboard does not seem warranted in a case like this.

Comment: Worth pointing out that 1002 was released in July 2018.  You might want to check if you already have the revision of the firmware installed.  If you do, then your motherboard already has the supported firmware, and that means you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I didn't know it wasn't supported when I bought the motherboard though that's why this happened.

Comment: Are you saying these motherboards come now already with a newer version of BIOS that does support it?

Comment: I can't find in the manual what version it has on it by default.  Could it damage the motherboard or cpu if I just plug everything and try it?

Comment: Use the ASUS firmware tool, or looking within the firmware, to determine your current revision.  Otherwise, use ASUS instructions to update the firmware.  This process might or might not require a compatible processor to be installed.  How you update the firmware on this motherboard is an entirely different question.  I am not saying the motherboards come with 1002.  That is not possible for ANYONE to say, it entirely depends on when it was produced, and what version of the firmware it was shipped with.  You should just update the firmware per the ASUS instructions.

Comment: I tried to turn it on with the processor in it and I'm getting no input on my monitor.  Does anyone know if it's possible to update the bios through a USB on this board without the CPU in?  Some ASUS boards have the Flashback USB button on the back, but this one doesn't have it.  I called the ASUS Tech support line and they said it should work without the button, by just plugging in a power source and a USB but I get no indication that anything is happening.  The board is lit up though...